# jQuery: multiple checkboxes, get the value of the only checked one

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I've got a script that shows a value when one checkbox is checked and doesn't show any value when more than one checkbox is checked.

This is working to a point.
If I select one checkbox I get the value associated to it's nearest `class=list`, if I click a second checkbox I get nothing and that is correct.

However when I unselect the second checkbox the alert shows it's value not the value of the last remaining checked check box.

So how do I get the value of the only checked checkbox ?

This is the layout of the checkbox and it's nearest `class list`

```
<tr>
<td>1</td><td><input type='checkbox' name='id[0]' id='0'/></td>
<td class='list'><span>1234</span></td>
<td><span></span></td>
</tr>
```

This is the jQuery I'm using :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var count;
    $(':checkbox').change(function() {
        count = ( $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length ) ;
        txt = $(this).closest('tr').find('.list').text();
        if (count == "1" ) {
            alert (txt)
        } 
    });
});
```

Here is a JSFiddle showing the issue : http://jsfiddle.net/f7qcuwkf/
If you check option 1 the alert shows 1234.

If you check option 3 then nothing shows (this is correct)  If you uncheck either option you see it's value and not the value of the remaining checked entry.  EG::

Uncheck 3 I get 3456, NOT 1234 ( 1 is still checked )

Any ideas how to resolve this ?

Thanks

Comment: Of course if you traverse the DOM with `this`, you'll get the vaue of the changed checkbox. You need to traverse the DOM with the checked box : http://jsfiddle.net/f7qcuwkf/2/

Comment: @Karl-André Gagnon thanks for the fast reply. if you post this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you traverse the DOM with `this`, you'll get the vaue of the changed checkbox. You need to traverse the DOM with the checked box. To do that, you can cache the selected checkboxes and traverse the DOM with it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var count;
    $(':checkbox').change(function() {
        var $checkboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
        count = ( $checkboxes.length ) ;

        if (count == "1" ) {
            var txt = $checkboxes.closest('tr').find('.list').text();
            alert (txt)
        } 
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f7qcuwkf/5/

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign `txt` variable this way (look for the closest row to the checked checkbox, and not to the one that was changed):

```
txt = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').closest('tr').find('.list').text();
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f7qcuwkf/4/)

Answer (score 0):

When you change, you are catching the text from the checkbox triggered, and not from the checkbox checked.

`$(":checkbox:checked").closest("tr").find('.list').text()`

http://jsfiddle.net/f7qcuwkf/1/